# How get list value in Userdefaults

Tags: swift3, nsuserdefaults

I have data with json in one func 1 get data have 1 list value but I go out func call value with userdefault I get 1 value.

```
func getdevices() {
    var token = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "token")
    print("token", token)
    var username = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "username")
    print("username", username)
    let url: URL = URL(string: "/public/devices")!
    let request: NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url)

    request.httpMethod = "Get"
    request.setValue(token , forHTTPHeaderField: "token")
    request.setValue(username, forHTTPHeaderField: "username")

    var responseError: NSError?
    var response: URLResponse?

    var urlData: Data?

    do {

        urlData = try NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request as URLRequest, returning:&response)

    } catch let error as NSError {
        responseError = error
        urlData = nil
    }
    if ( urlData != nil ) {
        let res = response as! HTTPURLResponse!;

        print("Response code: %ld tra ve" , res?.statusCode);

        if ((res?.statusCode)! >= 200 && (res?.statusCode)! < 300)
        {
            //let responseData:NSString  = NSString(data:urlData!, encoding:String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)!
            if let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: urlData!, options: []) as? [String : Any],
                //let dataArray = json?["status"] as? [String : Any],

                let items = json?["units"] as? [[String : Any]] {

                for item in items {

                    var lat = item["latitude"] as? String
                    UserDefaults.standard.set(lat, forKey: "latitude")
                    var test = UserDefaults.standard.double(forKey: "latitude")

                    print("test", test)

                    var long = item["longitude"] as? String
                    UserDefaults.standard.set(long, forKey: "longitude")

                    print("long", long)
                    var devid = item["devid"] as? String
                    UserDefaults.standard.set(devid, forKey: "devid")
                    var devname = item["devname"] as? String
                    UserDefaults.standard.set(devname, forKey: "devname")

                    var speed = item["speed"] as? String
                    UserDefaults.standard.set(speed, forKey: "speed")

                    var statustt = item["status"] as? String
                    UserDefaults.standard.set(statustt, forKey: "statusxe")
                    var drivername = item["drivername"] as? String
                    UserDefaults.standard.set(drivername, forKey: "drivername")
                    var address = item["address"] as? String
                    UserDefaults.standard.set(address, forKey: "address")

                    print("address", address)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But when the app exists the func it doesn't get the list data, it has one value.

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    GMSServices.provideAPIKey("AIzaSyB2IJzNc2s5km1qvdwAePDEat1OdPsOFVA")

    guard let address = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "address") else {return}
getdevices()

    var lat = UserDefaults.standard.double(forKey: "latitude")
    var long = UserDefaults.standard.double(forKey: "longitude")
    var devname = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "devname")
    var speed = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "speed")
    print("lat", lat)
    print("long", long)
    print("address***", address)



    let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: lat, longitude: long, zoom: 10)
    let mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: CGRect.zero, camera: camera)
    view = mapView
    let marKer = GMSMarker()
    marKer.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: lat, longitude: long)
    marKer.icon = UIImage(named: "vehicle_105")
    marKer.title = "Biển số \(devname)"
    //marKer.title = "Speed \(speed)"
    marKer.map = mapView

}
```

Comment: Please copy and paste code into your question instead of using images.  This will make it much easier for those answering to understand, and help you avoid your question getting flagged.

Comment: Not related but aren't you concerned about the many many warnings you get in your code? For example `sendSynchronousRequest` is deprecated for a couple of years.

Answer (score 0):

You can only store a single object/value under a single key in `UserDefaults`. The problem is, you are overwriting the value under the same key in each iteration of your loop. What you should do is create an array before the loop, add the values to that array inside the loop and store the array in `UserDefaults` after the loop finished its iterations.

```
if let items = json?["units"] as? [[String : Any]] {
    var latitudes = [String]()
    var longitudes = [String]() 
    var devids = [String]()
    var devnames = [String]()       
    var speeds = [String]()
    var statustts = [String]()
    var drivernames = [String]()
    var addresses = [String]()

    for item in items {
        let lat = item["latitude"] as? String
        latitudes.append(lat)            

        let long = item["longitude"] as? String
        longitudes.append(long)

        let devid = item["devid"] as? String
        devids.append(devid)

        var devname = item["devname"] as? String
        devnames.append(lat)

        var speed = item["speed"] as? String
        speeds.append(speed)

        var statustt = item["status"] as? String
        statuses.append(statustt)

        var drivername = item["drivername"] as? String
        drivernames.append(drivername)

        var address = item["address"] as? String
        addresses.append(address)
    }

    UserDefaults.standard.set(latitudes, forKey: "latitude")
    UserDefaults.standard.set(longitudes, forKey: "longitude")
    UserDefaults.standard.set(devids, forKey: "devid")
    UserDefaults.standard.set(devnames, forKey: "devname")
    UserDefaults.standard.set(speeds, forKey: "speed")
    UserDefaults.standard.set(statustts, forKey: "statusxe")
    UserDefaults.standard.set(drivername, forKey: "drivername")
    UserDefaults.standard.set(addresses, forKey: "address")
}
```